# Target only the 'li' that is the parent of an 'a' with a specific class

Tags: css, wordpress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

```
<ul class="page-numbers">
    <li><a href="/blog/page/1/" class="prev page-numbers">«</a></li>
    <li><a href="/blog/page/1/" class="page-numbers">1</a></li>
    <li><span class="page-numbers current">2</span></li>
    <li><a href="/blog/page/3/" class="page-numbers">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="/blog/page/4/" class="page-numbers">4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to target only the `li` that is the parent of `a.prev`? I can't use `first-child` because when I'm on the first page, `a.prev` doesn't show. Would appreciate any help on this. Thank you.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Answer (score 0):

Not with CSS only. [There are no parent selectors in CSS](http://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/).
However if you can/want to dive in to [javascript/jQuery](http://jquery.com/), you could do something like this:

```
$('.page-numbers a').closest('li').css({
    'height': '18px',
    'background': '#ccc'
});
```